# If it will do or If it does

Tags: future-tense

> I’ve decided to attend the course no mаtter if it (**will come / comes**)
>   in hаndy in the futurе or not.

Is it grammatically correct to use “will” after “if” in a case like this?

Answer (score -1):

You should say "if it comes".

From [Future Conditional Forms | ENGLISH PAGE](https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html):

> Future Real Conditional FORM [If / When ... simple present ..., ...
>   simple future ...]
>
> [... simple future ... if / when ... simple present ...]
>
> **Notice that there is no future in the if- or when-clause.**

Some examples:

> If I **go** to my friend's house for dinner tonight, I will take a bottle    of wine or some flowers.
>
> - I am still not sure if I will go to his house or not.
>
> --
>
> A: What are you going to do if it **rains**?
>
> B: I am going to stay at home.

There is also **Future Unreal Conditional**, but

> It is only used when a speaker needs to emphasize that something is
>   impossible

And Future Unreal Conditional doesn't use the form "if ... will" as well. See some examples:

Form 1 of Future Unreal Conditional:

> If I had a day off from work next week, I would go to the beach.
>
> - I don't have a day off from work.

Form 2 of Future Unreal Conditional:

> If I were going to Fiji next week, I would be taking my scuba diving
>   gear with me. In if-clause and result
>
> - I am not going to go to Fiji and I am not going to take my scuba gear
>     with me.

Form 3 of Future Unreal Conditional:

> If I were going to go to Fiji next week, I would be taking my scuba
>   diving gear with me.
>
> - I am not going to go to Fiji and I am not going to take my scuba gear
>     with me.